# How can I make an object with rigid body physics not return to the first keyframe when I try to animate it?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

Does anyone know how I can make an object with rigid body physics not return to its point of origin keyframe when I want to disable its animation?

What happens is that I'm trying to animate a ball going to a soccer goal, I have no problems to fit the keyframes for the movement of the ball trajectory to the goal net, but at the time of applying their respective rigid body physics, begins to experience failures, since at the time of having to apply its inertia for gravity to take effect and lower it, after hitting the net, the ball returns to the position of the first keyframe.

I have tried with CTRL + A to see if it is a problem of transformations, I have also tried to place the origin to the geometry of the ball before starting to animate, but it does not work, the net of the soccer goal is with physics in passive mode, in mesh form and in deform. The ball is the active one, with sphere shape. With the animate and dynamics button activated. The rigid body world is activated for both objects, gravity is also activated. I would be very grateful if you could help me. Greetings.

Translated with DeepL.com (free version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you made your rigid body animation until a certain point, and if i understood you right, you then want to animate your rigid body "manually" again.

For that you just can bake your rigid body animation to keyframes.

Example: you have a rigid body animation until frame 100.
You want to animate it manually from frame 101.

Select your rigid body object. Object -> rigid body -> bake to keyframes (use 100 as end keyframe).

Note: the rigid body will be deleted from your object. Just add a new one to it afterwards, if you need it again.

Comment: First of all thank you because it worked and my object does not return to the point of origin by doing what you recommended!